# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input - ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

**Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input**

Hi
I am getting this error when I fetch data from JSON file.
Error is: **"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"**

I am using my local server and file is downloaded in local server (CODE and FILE both are on same server)
Using this code:

const API = './data/posts.json';

```
componentDidMount(){
        fetch(API)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then( (data) => { console.log("data - ", data) } )
    }
```

and JSON file is   https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users?_format=json&access-token=PybsLaeEimY-agXScsQ-bFDdkFHDFH_sQMo3
but I have downloaded this file on local server

Thanks in Advance
Please Help

Comment: its working fine for me

Comment: may be you didn't stored valid json in `posts.json`

Comment: Yes, this error usually means the JSON is invalid.  I would suggest checking the posts.json file and verifying it is valid JSON.

Comment: First file JSON like this : [ {.........} ], and it's working fine.

Comment: Second JSON file : { {......} }, and it's not working (Error coming)